# Formula code in Word 2015 [mac]

Tags: macos, ms-word, formula

I'm currently making an invoice template in word, but I'm fighting with the formula code which is used.

Currently this is my table:
[image: Word 2015 table]

But, the number of rows wil depend on the days which I've worked. Right now, I have to manually alter the code to edit the cell-references (d9, b10, c10) if I create more rows.

Is there an easier way to do this? To let the cell-reference automatically change or change the formula code in a way that naming the cell-references isn't needed?

Thanks in advance :)

Other images of what I have:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Mac version behaves anything like the Window version then your best bet would be to BOOKMARK the cells. You can then use the bookmark names in the calculations instead of a cell reference.

For example, if you click at the left edge of the current D9, go to Insert/Bookmark and name it "Subtotal", then select cell B10 and insert a bookmark named "VAT" (both times *without* the double quotes ""!) you can use the bookmark names like this:

```
{ = { REF Subtotal } * { REF VAT } }
```

Note that it's sometimes possible to do this - { = Subtotal * VAT } - but that's not as certain as using a REF field.

Comment: If I bookmark the cells and put in the formula like you do, I get a Syntax error. If I remove the REF and the extra {}, then it works... but every time I update (cmd-a, f9) the total amount get's higher and higher. And the total per row is also defined with the reference (forgot to mention that, sorry), is there a way around that?

I've put in the images in the top post.

Comment: I've never used a Mac and some things don't work the same, so... Are you able to make a cross-reference to a cell bookmark (anywhere in the doc)? If so, what field code does that use? And can that be copied/pasted into the calculation successfully? Note that you might have better luck with this on SuperUser or some other end-user forum where there are more Mac users that do calculations - there may well be something Mac-specific I wouldn't know about.

Comment: I made the bookmark via insert > bookmark. It does give the correct amount if I just reference {name-bookmark}. But, thanks for the help you gave already! I'm one step further to the answer thanks to you. I'll upvote you.

Comment: For any readers interested in this question, this is the link to the superuser question: http://superuser.com/questions/1038685/formula-code-in-word-2015-mac

Comment: @Cindy Meister: Don't you find that when you reference a bookmarked *cell* in a calculation, when you update the calculation result, the result just keeps getting larger and larger? And that is regardless of how you reference the bookmark - just using "theBookmark", { theBookmark }, { REF theBookmark } or { =theBookmark }. Perhaps easier to see if the bookmarked cell contains a calculation such as { =SUM(ABOVE) }.