# MS Word table formula for value of cell above

Tags: ms-word, formula, word-2010, fieldcodes

Is there a way in MS Word to get in table the value of the **cell above** for calculation?

I want to calculate the percentage of the sum.

[image: example tabel]

I can build the **sum** with the formular `=SUM(ABOVE)`, but I couldn't find a link to the value of the cell above. `XXX` in the table should be replace by a formula, something like that:

```
value_of_cell_above (74.970) * 0,2 => 14.994
```

Comment: See my Answer in this discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316313/formula-code-in-word-2015-mac/35319375#35319375 Word field codes can only do absolute cell references, but you can bookmark the cell.

Comment: I didn't see this as a duplicate, because it is about the specific case of "1 above", which is potentially different from the case of "get the value of a cell from anywhere in the table". I also think the current Answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316313/formula-code-in-word-2015-mac/35319375#35319375 is incorrect, as per comments. But now that *this* question has been marked as a duplicate, IMO it would be better to correct the other answer if necessary and probably delete this question. Perhaps Cindy Meister could merge my answer on SU into hers? (I am away for a week).

Comment: You are right @bibadia you answer specific the problem of the cell above. But your solution could be derived by the as duplicated marked answer.

Comment: @wittich: if you think your *question* is a duplicate, IMO you could voluntarily remove it. All that matters then is that there is a *good* answer to the other one. My perception is that as it stands, it isn't correct.

Comment: @bibadia I don't know what to do. I like your answer as it answer exact my question. I think when somebody has in feature exact the same question your answer is better then the one of [Cindy Meister](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3077495/cindy-meister). I marked the question as duplicate before I got your answer.

Comment: @wittich: I don't think it is going to do much harm to leave things exactly as they are, at least for now!

Comment: I have the same problem and the same setup. For a specific solution to your setup but not a way to address "the cell above" you could just use SUM(ABOVE) again in the following way: =SUM(ABOVE)/2*0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word's cell addressing is quite crude and doesn't have a facility for this.

In this case, your best bet is probably to use a nested field to assign the result of your `=SUM(ABOVE)` to a bookmark, then reference the bookmark.

e.g. in row 3, column 2, put

```
{ SET theSum { =SUM(ABOVE) } }{ theSum }
```

in row 4, column 2, put

```
{ ={ theSum }*0.2 }
```

All the `{}` have to be the special field code brace pairs that you can insert using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> on Windows Word and typically <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd>  + <kbd>F9</kbd> on Mac Word.

There is a case for wrapping up sequences of fields inside a `{ QUOTE }` field to increase the chance that if anyone deletes anything in the cell, they delete the whole calculation and not just part of it. It's sometimes easier to spot problems in that case e.g.

```
{ QUOTE { SET theSum { =SUM(ABOVE) } }{ theSum } }
```

Most of the spaces in these field codes can be removed if you prefer a minimalist approach.

Comment: Thx also for the tip using `{ QUOTE ... }`, that's really helpful for refreshing the results.